# Xcode asked me to replace something and i did, now my xcode doesn't work properly?

Tags: ios, xcode

My xcode asked me to replace something, not sure what, it had to do with the test folder of my project so i just accepted it since xcode recommended it. Now every time i do something in interface builder i get an error. I spent probably 40 hours on the project in interface builder but now everything i do gives me an error... What should i do?
I searched for way to load an old saved file of the project but i found that this is not possible so right now i'm stuck with a project that gives me errors every time i add something or change something.

EDIT: I'm guessing i'm in test mode or something since it gives me really dumb errors that are  obvious but i don't know how to come back to the normal mode.

Comment: Description is not helpful please post exact error which you get.

Comment: Can you create a new project and move things over?

Comment: Here's one problem: When i put a UITableview in the interface builder i get this error: "Static table cells are only valid embedded in UITableview instances". As i said i've been working on the project for more then 40 hours, i've used UITableview a lot in this project. Since i made the Changes that xcode asked me to do, i get the error when i use a UITableview.

Comment: When I see a question saying that there was an error without specifying what the error was, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" 9 times out of 9. Unless you're using an Apple II, error messages actually say something other than just "Error", and they do that for a reason: The information is useful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XCode asked you to change something automatically, it probably had created a snapshot of your project. 
You can revert from the File Menu > Restore Snapshot.

Comment: YES! It was something about Snapshots. Do you know why since i created a snapshot everything i do gives me an error?

Comment: I think XCode automatically update some old settings in your project. But before, it creates a snapshot. The problem is not the snapshot but the project update. You have to restore at the last snapshot to revert and probably resolve your compilation errors.

Comment: I don't remember if you can choose to create the snapshot or not but I hope you did it if XCode asked you.

Comment: I just did restore to the last snapshot (which was the only snapshot i had) and i still have errors and it still ask me to perform changes and save a snapshot... I'm really confused.

Comment: Weird ! Try to clean project : CMD+K then CMD+Alt+K

Comment: It got rid of the errors! Thanks! But it stills ask me to perform changes... It says :" Project 'CallOfDutyMaps' - Automatically select architectures. Project 'CallOfDutyMaps' overrides the architectures setting. This will remove the setting and allow xcode to automatically select architertures based on hardware available for the active platform and deployment target." If i select: "Perform changes" This is when they ask me to save a snapshot and this is when is messed my xcode but giving me bunch of error. What should i do with the automatically select architectures thing?

Comment: Yes it will ask you to perform changes until you perform it. I recommend you to fix that because you could have problems during Apple validation process. Fix it manually until warning disappear.Take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898999/xcode-5-warns-about-my-architectures-setting-when-i-open-my-google-maps-project ?